Calculate sliding "image similarity" score similar to conv2d
I have a large image and a smaller "kernel" image. I would like to compare the kernel with each part of the image (by "sliding" the kernel across the image) and retrieve a "similarity tensor" (indicating how similar the kernel is to the image patch at the shifted position). This is very much like conv2d, but my kernel is an RGB/HSV image and thus not a valid convolution kernel.
For example if my kernel image is black, conv2d would return 0 everywhere as similarity to any image, but I want similarity to be 1 if the large image is black in a certain region.
I have written this inefficient method to demonstrate what I want:
def tensor_kernel_similarity(image, kernel, stride = 1):

    assert len(kernel.shape) == 3
    assert len(image.shape) == 4

    similarity = torch.zeros((1,
                              int((image.shape[-2]-kernel.shape[-2])/stride)+1, 
                             int((image.shape[-1]-kernel.shape[-1])/stride)+1), dtype=torch.float, device=image.device)
    for b in range(0, similarity.shape[0]):
        for y in range(0, similarity.shape[1]):
            for x in range(0, similarity.shape[2]):
                image_patch = image[b,:, y*stride:y*stride+kernel.shape[1], x*stride:x*stride+kernel.shape[2]]
                
                #pad image patch to kernel size:
                if kernel.shape[2]-image_patch.shape[2] + kernel.shape[1]-image_patch.shape[1] > 0:
                    image_patch = F.pad(image_patch, (0, kernel.shape[2]-image_patch.shape[2], 0, kernel.shape[1]-image_patch.shape[1]), value=0)
                
                # calculate the diff between the image patch and the kernel (in the range [0,1])
                diff = image_patch.sub(kernel).abs().sum()/kernel.nelement()
                # similarity is the inverse of the diff
                sim = 1 - diff
                # store similarity in the output tensor                
                similarity[b,y,x] = sim
    return similarity

Is there a way to use conv2d instead to get what I want? Or is there a way to significantly speed this code up?

Isn't it a small mistake on the image_patch definition? image has shape [bs, h, w, c] and the patch are from slices on w and c dimension instead of h, w? Plus, I think it would be more readable if you set some variable for each shape of tensor : bs, h_image, w_image, c_image = image.shape for example? Plus formatting the code with any PEP8 formatter would be nice.


Do you mean you want to perform a 2D-correlation of a kernel with an image?


do you have a definition of what you mean with 2d-correlation?

See "Digital Image Processing 4e", to me it's what you want. Notably, equation 3-34.

@Philipp A correlation is basically the same as a convolution, but with a flipped kernel. So that's probably not what you want, since you calculate the absolute difference between your kernel and the current image patch. What I don't understand is the sim = 1 - diff calculation. Do you know that the maximum value of diff, i.e. the sum of absolute differences between your image patch and your kernel is 1? Otherwise that doesn't make sense to me.

@simon this correlation/convolution thing is my understanding as well. So I agree that this is not what I want. The images are normalized to 0 (black)...1 (white) and I'm dividing by the number of elements in the kernel, so yes, the max. diff is 1.

@Philipp I missed the normalization step (…/kernel.nelement()). That makes sense, thanks for clarifying!

You can use torch.Tensor.unfold() to gain some significant speedup. With unfold(), you can produce a sliding window view into your given image tensor, which you can then compare to your kernel without explicit for loops (see the code comments for the intermediate tensor shapes):
def proposed(image, kernel, stride=1):
    # ^ image: [b, c, hi, wi], kernel: [c, hk, wk], stride=s
    patched = image.unfold(-2, kernel.shape[-2], stride)
    # ^ patched: [b, c, (hi-hk)//s+1, wi, hk]
    patched = patched.unfold(-2, kernel.shape[-1], stride)
    # ^ patched: [b, c, (hi-hk)//s+1, (wi-wk)//s+1, hk, wk]
    patched = patched.movedim(-5, -3)
    # ^ patched: [b, (hi-hk)//s+1, (wi-wk)//s+1, c, hk, wk]
    _n = 1 / kernel.nelement()
    sim = patched.sub(kernel).abs_().sum(dim=(-3, -2, -1)).mul_(_n).neg_().add_(1)
    # ^ sim: [b, (hi-hk)//s+1, (wi-wk)//s+1]
    return sim

Here is how I tested it:
from timeit import Timer

import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# FIXME: Add code for `tensor_kernel_similarity()` and `proposed()` here

torch.manual_seed(42)

# TODO: Adjust parameters as necessary
device = torch.device("cpu")
s = 2
b, c, hi, wi = 1, 3, 101, 101
hk, wk = 10, 9
assert b == 1  # In `tensor_kernel_similarity()`, the value of `similarity.shape[0]` is hard-coded to 1

# Create some random test data with values in [0., 1.)
img = torch.rand(size=(b, c, hi, wi)).to(device)
knl = torch.rand(size=(c, hk, wk)).to(device)

given = tensor_kernel_similarity(img, knl, stride=s)
own = proposed(img, knl, stride=s)
assert torch.allclose(given, own)
print("Timing given:", Timer(lambda: tensor_kernel_similarity(img, knl, stride=s)).timeit(100))
print("Timing proposed:", Timer(lambda: proposed(img, knl, stride=s)).timeit(100))

This gave me on the CPU:
Timing given: 9.2…
Timing proposed: 0.05…

And on the GPU (device = torch.device("cuda:0")):
Timing given: 18.8…
Timing proposed: 0.009…

Two caveats:

You will probably notice the time-vs-memory tradeoff here. In particular, with patched.sub(kernel), the memory of patched has to be inflated to the full size of the sliding window view – patched.sub_(kernel), i.e. an in-place change of patched, would lead to wrong results since the elements of the memory that is underlying the view would be overwritten multiple times. If you run into limitations here, consider maybe a hybrid between your current approach and mine. Also, if you want to have both (fast code and no intermediate memory peak, that is), you might be better off sticking to a "loopy" approach and accelerating it with something like Numba.
I am not sure if all situations are handled the same way between your current approach and mine. I successfully tested with all combinations for s in [1, 2, 3], hi in [99, 100, 101], wi in [99, 100, 101], hk in [9, 10, 11], wk in [9, 10, 11], but maybe I overlooked some cases.

